# Do positive semidefinite matrix have LU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Suppose we have a real matrix $A=R R^t$ where $R$ is triangular. Since there is no restriction on $R$ we can say that $A$ is positive semidefinite. Can I affirm that $A$ has LU decomposition (L lower triangular with ones on the diagonal and U upper triangular)?

Comment: If your matrix $A$ is singular, then the $LU$ decomposition will fail.

Comment: Any diagonal matrix has a LU decomposition @PC1

Comment: @nicomezi $ \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $ is diagonal and has no LU decomposition.

Comment: $L= I_2$ and $U$ as your matrix works, right ? @S4JJ4D

Comment: @nicomezi in LU decomposition, $U$ must be nonsingular. At least this is the definition of LU that I know of.

Comment: In that case I agree with you, the matrix your proposed has no LU decomposition. But that is not the definition given in this question and the one I know on my side (and presented on wikipedia, as far as it has a value).

Comment: If we consider just the structure of LU, ie, L is lower triangular with ones on the diagonal, and U upper triangular, then: singular matrix may have LU decompositions. @nicomezi $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You _can_ find a $LU$ decomposition for a singular matrix, however this decomposition will also be singular. Maybe there are some use cases for this, however this is probably rare.